# How to address cataclysmic ubuntu failures?

Tags: boot, partitioning

Ever since repartitioning my SSD hardrive to increase swap size (from zero), I have been experiencing intermittent, catastrophic failures. The worst occurred tonight; I had to hard-reboot several times (I'm currently posting using a live USB).

The trouble started during a browsing session with firefox (the latest version). Everything froze, REISUB was non-responsive, and I had to hard-reboot. After that several very scary things happened. I was dumped into the system's boot utility (blue-screen menu containing booting options), which appeared to lack the usual booters. Hitting ESC resulted in the following very concerning display: 
[image: crash_pic_1]

I immediately rebooted again, which resulted in another equally scary screen:

[image: crash_pic_2]

I performed the 'check disk for defects' option on the live USB, which found no errors.

I'm at a complete loss; don't even know what questions to ask. Please help!

Comment: It looks like your hard drive might be dying. Try an extended SMART test in the Disks application, which should be included on an Ubuntu live USB/DVD.

Comment: fyi: the 'check disk for defects' looks at your install media (usb-thumb-drive), and not your device sda (first hdd/sdd)

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I tried your suggestion twice. The first time, the Disks utility seemed to have some errors; several of the buttons returned errors. So I rebooted the liveUSB; now the Disks utility cannot find the laptop hard drive; it displays only two devices, the live usb and a '1.5 GB loop device', which is not the hard drive.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex: Tried Disks again, and it seems to have found the device, but can't mount: the following error appears --
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64 busy